# AngularJS routing not working during bootstrap, works after that

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, typescript, angular-ui-router

I've been on this for a couple of days now and I feel I am missing something. I want to create a webapp and started to set up my angularjs base. While setting up my angularjs base I ran into a routing problem. The problem looks like a race condition but I cannot seem to find where it lies.

When starting my angularjs website routing is not functioning. Even putting `$location.path("/dashboard");` in the module.run does not show the correct views. BUT when I go to the address bar of my browser after the website is loaded and remove the 'dashboard' in '#/dashboard', it redirects me to '#/dashboard' and showing the correct view. It looks that routing is not working while bootstrapping my angular webapp.

I tried both `ngRoute` and `UI-Router`. Both result in the same.

Webapp on [github](https://github.com/Cezus/MonetaryReign).

[image: The problem]

app.ts:

```
require(['angular', 'ui-router'], (angular) => {
angular.module('monetaryreign.services', []);
angular.module('monetaryreign.ui', []);
var app = angular.module('monetaryreign', ['ui.router', 'monetaryreign.services', 'monetaryreign.ui']);

app.run(startup)

startup.$inject = ['$location'];

function startup($location) {
    $location.path("/dashboard");
}

require(['angular', 'app/app.states'], (angular) => {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['monetaryreign']);
});
});
```

app.states.ts:

```
import angular = require('angular');
import dashboard = require('app/dashboard/dashboard.controller');

function routes($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider, $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider) {
var f = dashboard
var baseUrl = document.getElementById('base-url').getAttribute('value');

$stateProvider
    .state('dasboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: baseUrl + 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })

$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/dashboard');

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
}

routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

angular
.module('monetaryreign')
.config(routes);
```

Comment: Did you try removing the line : $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/dashboard');

Comment: Thank you for your comment, just tried. Not solved unfortunately.

Comment: And removing the $location.path("/dashboard"); as well ?

Comment: If I remove that statement in the module.run nothing happens at all. Client-side routing does not take place (routing does not add the '#' in the url)

Answer (score 0):

Try remove this lines.

```
app.run(startup)

startup.$inject = ['$location'];

function startup($location) {
    $location.path("/dashboard");
}
```

And this one too

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/dashboard');
```

Should work

Comment: Thank you for your help, it did not work unfortunatly. It still doesn't go to http://localhost/#/ when I enter **http://localhost**.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `$urlProvider.html5mode(true)` to the app config and the tag `<base href="/">` into the head part of your HTML.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. When posting an answer, try to be more informative: explain the error you have found and the solution you have posted: see also how to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer